# If I update my device's system PublisherHostId will remain the same?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uniqueidentifier

In my windows phone 8 app I use PublisherHostId. If user after installing my app updates him device's system, will this PublisherHostId remain the same?

Comment: What are you using `PublisherHostId` for?

Comment: this id I use on my service for identify different devices